# How to be DRY in python 2 given lack of pass-by-reference

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write some Python code which currently looks like this:

```
if validator("foo", "bar"):
    self.a = accessor("foo", "bar")
if validator("xxx", "yyy"):
    self.b = accessor("xxx", "yyy")
```

This is all contained in a class method, and self.a and self.b are instance variables.

I'd like to avoid all this repetition of arguments for validator() and accessor(). If python had pass-by-reference I'd do something like this:

```
def validate_and_access(self, target_ref, parm1, parm2)
    if validator(parm1, parm2):
        target_ref = accessor(parm1, parm2)
```

Given that I don't have pass-by-reference, is there another way? I considered using getattr() to access the instance variables by name as a string, or perhaps even defining a dictionary to contain the instance variables, but both of those seem overkill and rather clunky.

Comment: One solution would be to have `validate_and_access()` return either `target` or `accessor(parm1, parm2)` (depending on the test result), then have the caller assign the value returned by `validate_and_access()` to the original `target` variable.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: That would involve an assignment of the target variable even if its value was unchanged. In this specific case it probably doesn't matter much, and I like this better than using setattr().

Answer (score 6):

Based on your pass-by-reference example, can you not do something like this?

```
def validate_and_access(self, target_ref, parm1, parm2)
    if validator(parm1, parm2):
        setattr(self, target_ref, accessor(parm1, parm2))
```

Comment: yes I could, but I was hoping for something a bit less fragile than setattr(). In your example I could feed the function a string which didn't correspond to an instance variable name.  Maybe I'm too accustomed to strongly typed languages...

Comment: If the member should already be defined in your object, you could check that the name is already an attribute before setting it, with `hasattr`. But yes, many languages differ greatly in the "correct stylish way to code things".